# what is the meaning of giving an offset of 256 in a 16 bit image, while reading it from binary file?

Tags: java, image-processing

Consider the code-

```
if(shiftFlag == 8)// shiftflag is for U8 type image
                {
                    System.out.println("This is an 8 bit image");
                    for(i=0;i<fsize;i++)
                    {
                        pix[i]=255;
                        if(Bands!=1)
                        {
                            if(pix_rgb[p-1][i]>=0)
                                pix1[i]= pix_rgb[p-1][i];
                            else
                                pix1[i]= 256+pix_rgb[p-1][i];

                            if(pix_rgb[q-1][i]>=0)
                                pix2[i]= pix_rgb[q-1][i];
                            else
                                pix2[i]= 256+pix_rgb[q-1][i];

                            if(pix_rgb[r-1][i]>=0)
                                pix3[i]= pix_rgb[r-1][i];
                            else
                                pix3[i]= 256+pix_rgb[r-1][i];
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            if(pix_rgb[0][i]>=0)
                            {
                                pix1[i]= pix_rgb[0][i];
                                pix2[i]=pix1[i];
                                pix3[i]=pix1[i];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pix1[i]= 256+pix_rgb[0][i];
                                pix2[i]=pix1[i];
                                pix3[i]=pix1[i];
                            }
                         }
```

Why a 256 offset is given in case of U8 image?
Can you please explain the code and its significance in reading a binary image of U16 datatype?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Please don't tag-spam, only use really relevant tags. The question has nothing to do with [tag:python].

Comment: 256 is an interesting number written in binary. Here the addition sets a bit